# Having Trouble Webscraping Cronometer.com using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, home-assistant

I'm very new to Python, but using a few different online guides I've managed to stitch together some code that logs me into a website called cronometer.com (health tracking website/app, similar to myfitnesspal). Unfortunately, I'm having trouble actually scraping any data.

I have the following code (ignore the Hass/AppDaemon, I'm running this python script in Home Assistant):

```
import appdaemon.plugins.hass.hassapi as hass
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import requests

class Scraper(hass.Hass):

  def initialize(self):
    self.log("Scraper Initialized")
    self.get_values(self)

  def get_values(self,kwargs):
    self.login_url = "https://cronometer.com/login/"
    self.r = requests.get(self.login_url)
    self.bs = BeautifulSoup(self.r.text, 'html.parser')
    self.csrf_token = self.bs.find('input', attrs={'name': 'anticsrf'})['value']
    self.url = "https://cronometer.com/"
    self.session = requests.Session()
    self.payload = {
        "username": "MY_USERNAME",
        "password": "MY_PASSWORD",
        "anticsrf": self.csrf_token
    }
    self.headers = {'referer': self.login_url, 'User-agent': 'Chrome'}
    self.sensorname = "sensor.scraper"
    self.friendly_name = "Fasting Status"
    
    try:
      s = self.session.post(self.login_url, data=self.payload, headers=self.headers, cookies=self.r.cookies)
    except:
      self.log("Could not log in")
      return
    
    self.log(self.csrf_token)
    s = self.session.get(self.url)
    page = s.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

    # Test 1
    fasting1 = soup.select('#cronometerApp > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) > div > div:nth-child(8) > div > div.diary-item-title > div')
    self.log("TEST 1")
    self.log(fasting1)

    # Test 2
    fasting2 = soup.select('#cronometerApp > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) > div > div:nth-child(8) > div > div.diary-item-content > div.GJES3IWDERB')
    self.log("TEST 2")
    self.log(fasting2)

    # Test 3
    fasting3 = soup.select('#w-node-dd7aab6f-acfc-dfa1-2372-313b5d39fc2b-0dd15747 > div.div__mobile__features-text-1 > h5')
    self.log("TEST 3")
    self.log(fasting3)

    # Test 4
    fasting4 = soup.select('#cronometerApp > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > div > div.GJES3IWDHFD > button:nth-child(1) > span')
    self.log("TEST 4")
    self.log(fasting4)

    # Test 5
    fasting5 = soup.select('#cronometerApp > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > div > div.diary_side_box.GJES3IWDIQB > div.GJES3IWDKQB > div > div.GJES3IWDITE > table > tbody > tr > td > div:nth-child(1) > span')
    self.log("TEST 5")
    self.log(fasting5)

    self.set_state(self.sensorname, state= "Test", attributes = {"friendly_name": self.friendly_name})
```

From what I can tell, this code successfully logs into cronometer.com with no issues. The problem is (I think) the URL for my personal homepage is the same URL for the website *before* logging in. So after using `session.post` to send my credentials to the website, I'm using `session.get` to scrape data from my "profile". But it's only scraping data from the normal cronometer.com webpage (before you login), not my own personal webpage with the same URL.

One thing I did notice is that the URL does change slightly when I click on the tabs at the top, as you can see here:

[image]

When I click on Diary, the URL changes from cronometer.com to cronometer.com/#diary, and Trends is cronometer.com/#trends, so on and so forth. But using those specific URLs is not proving fruitful either.

Again, sorry for my lack of knowledge, but how can I overcome this issue? I've tried looking at some online guides about Selenium, but so far I haven't been able to make sense of how I could use Selenium to log in when the issue isn't necessarily logging in (I don't think), but scraping the right webpage. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You could try using `session` also for the login request

Answer (score 2):

You are using the requests module, which is an amazing tool for scraping static/server-side rendered content.

Cronometer, however, is a javascript app.
If you disable the javascript and try to load cronometer, you will be greeted by the "Your web browser must have javascript enabled" message.

[image]
This is basically what your `requests` call will see as well.

Scraping websites like these is an easy task with tools like [requests-html module](https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/) and [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).

I personally like selenium as it is extremely easy to use, and you can actually see what the script is doing in a chrome browser in real-time.

I wrote a piece of code that logs into cronometer and scrapes the daily energy value.
I've added comments explaining what every line does.

```py
import chromedriver_autoinstaller
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

# setup selenium (I am using chrome here, so chrome has to be installed on your system)
chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()
options = Options()
# if you set this to true the chrome window will not be displayed 
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

URL = 'https://cronometer.com/login/'
USERNAME = ''
PASSWORD = ''

# navigate to cronometer
driver.get(URL)

# fill inputs
driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value='username').send_keys(USERNAME)
driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value='password').send_keys(PASSWORD)

# click on the login button
driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value='login-button').click()

# wait until the daily energy bar loads, or skip if 10 seconds have passed
timeout = 10
expectation = EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.nutrientTargetBar-text'))
nutrients_element = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(expectation)

# print daily energy bar text
print(nutrients_element.text)
```